# How to pass an ng-model into function for web service?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, I'd like to fire a web request that is dependent on an ng-model that is passed in. I'm not sure how I can pass it in correctly. The ng-model should be the function's `sortval`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th ng-model="User" ng-click="getAdminList()">User</th>
        <th ng-model="First Name" ng-click="getAdminList()">First Name</th>
        <th ng-model="Last Name" ng-click="getAdminList()">Last Name</th>
        <th ng-model="Job Title" ng-click="getAdminList()">Job Title</th>
        <th ng-model="EmpID" ng-click="getAdminList()">Emp ID</th>
        <th ng-model="OfficerCode" ng-click="getAdminList()">Officer Code</th>
        <th ng-model="Email" ng-click="getAdminList()">Email</th>
        <th ng-model="Telephone" ng-click="getAdminList()">Telephone</th>
        <th ng-model="Fax"ng-click="getAdminList()">Fax Number</th>
        <th ng-model="Location" ng-click="getAdminList()">Location Description</th>
        <th ng-model="Mailstop" ng-click="getAdminList()">Mailstop / Banking Center #</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my function:

```
    $scope.getAdminList = function(sortval) {
    adminList = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: this.prepContext(siteOrigin+"/corporate/projecthub/anchormn/associates","User Administration","?$orderBy=" + sortval + "&$top=1000&$filter=UserStatus eq 'Active'"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      //$("#articleSection").fadeIn(2000);
      console.log("adminlist", data.data.d.results);
      $scope.users = data.data.d.results;
    });
  };
```

Comment: ng-model is for forms, not for elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ng-click` attributes, just pass the string.

```
<th ng-click="getAdminList('User')">User</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-model should be used over form elements, however if you need to pass value to the ng-click function, you can just pass it as a string

```
 <th ng-model="Last Name" ng-click="getAdminList('Last Name')">Last Name</th>
```